# SenseNet Newly created content not showing up when querying for it

Tags: sensenet

I have initialized the DefaultDatabase

When I create any new content anywhere it does not show up when I'm querying for it.

I can access it when I know the exact path.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Thanks for your help

**Edit1**:
I'm using 7.7.8

Used for example this code

```cs
    await Tools.EnsurePathAsync("Root/IMS/ImsTestDomain", "Domain").ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Tools.EnsurePathAsync("Root/ImsTestDomains", "Domains").ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Tools.EnsurePathAsync("Root/ImsTestDomains/ImsTestDomain", "Domain").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

then I'm using GET Request like these

```
    /odata.svc/Root
    /odata.svc/Root/IMS
    /odata.svc/Root/ImsTestDomains
```

or like these

- notice the "query=Type" - filtering for Domains or Domain
- taken from https://admin.sensenet.com/

```
    /odata.svc/Root?%24orderby=DisplayName%20asc&%24select=Id%2CPath%2CName%2CType%2CDisplayName%2CIcon%2CIsFolder%2CParentId%2CVersion%2CPageCount%2CBinary%2CCreationDate%2CAvatar%2CActions&%24expand=Actions&query=Type%3ADomains%20.AUTOFILTERS%3AOFF&metadata=no&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=10000  
    /odata.svc/Root?%24orderby=DisplayName%20asc&%24select=Id%2CPath%2CName%2CType%2CDisplayName%2CIcon%2CIsFolder%2CParentId%2CVersion%2CPageCount%2CBinary%2CCreationDate%2CAvatar%2CActions&%24expand=Actions&query=Type%3ADomain%20.AUTOFILTERS%3AOFF&metadata=no&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=10000
```

Comment: Hi, please tell us more about your environment. What kind of project are you using and which api did you use for content creation and querying? And also, which version of sensenet :).

Comment: It is possible that you've created a content under a _system folder_. That means a query will not return anything there by default, you have to _switch autofilters off_ to get system content results.